# Open popover box on specific coordinates in android Canvas

Tags: android, graphics

I have draw a map using android canvas (In **ondraw(Canvas canvas)** )callback method),
my requirement is that i want open pop-overview whenever user touch any node of map should we remember pop-overview is open in front of node which have been drawn by canvas, We have drawn multipal node by **canvas.drawrect()**;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
int x,y;
wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
wmlp.x = x; // x position
wmlp.y = y; // y position
// Code for fetching the Coordinates of x,y.
```